# Installation of opencv-contrib-python through pip3 fails

Tags: raspbian, python-3

I typed the code

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

it responded with

```
"Collecting opencv-contrib-python"
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python(from version： ）
No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python
```

I'm using Raspbian Stretch on the raspberry pi 3.

Comment: Read the FAQ on this page https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/

Answer (score 1):

There's no source distribution available on PyPI, only wheels (for non-Pi platforms) are provided, hence no matching distribution.

You can get v3.4.4.19 from [piwheels.org](https://www.piwheels.org). We are currently building the latest version (v4.x) but it's not available yet.

If you specify the version you should be able to get it:

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.4.19
```

Note you'll also need various dependencies documented here: https://blog.piwheels.org/new-opencv-builds/